# Re-writing from switch to if else

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement

Need help changing this C program from switch to if or if else statements for a homework assignment. I'm new to coding so just a push in the right direction is all I need. The program is designed to read letters i.e "a/A" and then output the total number of times that letter was inputted. I just need a way to convert it from switch cases to if and if else statements.

```
/* Counting letter grades */

#include <stdio.h>

/* function main begins program execution */
int main( void ) 
{ 
int grade; /* one grade */
int aCount = 0; /* number of As */
int bCount = 0; /* number of Bs */ 
int cCount = 0; /* number of Cs */ 
int dCount = 0; /* number of Ds */
int fCount = 0; /* number of Fs */

printf(  "Enter the letter grades.\n"  ); 
printf(  "Enter the EOF character ('m')to end input.\n"  );

/* loop until user types 'm' */ 
while ((grade=getchar()) !='m') { 

/* determine which grade was input */
switch (grade) {  /* switch nested in while */

  case 'A':      /* grade was uppercase A */
  case 'a':      /* or lowercase a */
      ++aCount;  /* increment aCount */
      break;     /* necessary to exit switch */

  case 'B':     /* grade was uppercase B */
  case 'b':     /* or lowercase b */
      ++bCount;  /* increment bCount */
      break;     /* exit switch */

  case 'C':     /* grade was uppercase C */
  case 'c':     /* or lowercase c */
      ++cCount; /* increment cCount */
      break;    /* exit switch */

  case 'D':     /* grade was uppercase D */
  case 'd':     /* or lowercase d */
      ++dCount; /* increment dCount */
      break;    /* exit switch */

  case 'F':     /* grade was uppercase F */ 
  case 'f':     /* or lowercase f */ 
     ++fCount; /* increment fCount */
     break;    /* exit switch */

  case '\n':   /* ignore newlines, */ 
  case '\t':   /* tabs, */
  case ' ' :   /* and spaces in input */
      break;   /* exit switch */

  default:    /* catch all other characters */
     printf( "Incorrect letter grade entered." );
     printf( " Enter a new grade.\n" );
      break;  /* optional; will exit switch anyway */
  }         /* end switch */ 
}           /* end while */

/* output summary of results */
 printf( "\nTotals for each letter grade are:\n" );
 printf( "A: %d\n", aCount ); /* display number of A grades */
 printf( "B: %d\n", bCount ); /* display number of B grades */
 printf( "C: %d\n", cCount ); /* display number of C grades */
 printf( "D: %d\n", dCount ); /* display number of D grades */
 printf( "F: %d\n", fCount ); /* display number of F grades */ 
 return 0; /* indicate program ended successfully */ 
} /* end function main */
```

Comment: That's such a simple task that I can't think of a way to give a hint that's short of just giving the answer. What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson2.html

Comment: Hint: when you have a bunch of variables of the same type with the same name that only differ by an ordinal or a prefix (as you have here), that's a really strong hint you want to use an *array*.  It's not an issue for this assignment, but it's something you may want to keep in mind for the future.

Comment: Thanks for the link its exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as simple as that:

```
if(grade == 'A' || grade == 'a')
    ++aCount;
else if(grade == 'B' || grade == 'b')
    ++bCount;
else if(grade == 'C' || grade == 'c')
    ++cCount;    
else if(grade == 'D' || grade == 'd')
    ++dCount;  
else if(grade == 'F' || grade == 'f')
    ++fCount;
else if(grade == '\n' || grade == '\t' || grade == ' ')
    ++fCount; 
else {
    printf( "Incorrect letter grade entered." );
    printf( " Enter a new grade.\n" );
}
```

Here if a body of an if or else-if statement is executed, the other bodies will not be executed.

PS: Check this helpful [Cprogramming Tutorial](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson2.html).

Comment: Looks like you forgot the whitespace cases.

Comment: what does whitespace mean? @Zong

Comment: Zong means this `case ' ' :   /* and spaces in input */` @pwndaman, the spaces for simplicity.